# регулярка для телефона

Tags: php

Ищу по рег.выражению рос.телефон в тексте из групп вк

```
/((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3,5}\)?[\- ]?)[\d\- ]{5,10}/ui
```

телефоны находит всегда, только вот иногда первым значением пробиваются цифры из ссылки на юзеров   `https://vk.com/id453338121`  , которые могут быть в тексте. Подскажите, как и исключать такие моменты ?

Comment: Не люблю составлять регулярки) Два года назад нашел вот эту `/^((8|\+)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$/i`, юзаю до сих пор. Вроде не подводит

Comment: спасибо конечно, но явно не изучили мой вопрос

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian в каком смысле "явно не изучили"? Вы проверяли то, что Вам посоветовали? Под ту регулярку что Вам посоветовали, ссылки на юзеров не попадают. Проверить можно, например, тут: https://regex101.com/

Comment: да, убрав `^` поиск начал работать как следует . Прошу прощения